# How to create new model into existing loopback project "Loop Back"

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I've cloned a loopback project from git. Now I want to add a new model into existing project. I'm confused what steps I need to do again, and How I can create new model. my project is "**D:\projects\loopback**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to to director of your project and use lb model then you will be able to create new model. but you must have install lb ,npm.. look loopback documentaions.